# Run Runas without password prompt

Tags: command-line, batch, administrator, prompt, runas

First of all, I'm sorry to register a new question when there are a few about the same subject, but I couldn't find a specific answer...

I'm trying to create a batch file to be used by a regular user. The goal is to run a batch file that opens task manager and kills any process with high RAM usage, but the user doesn't have access to Task Manager.

So far I have this code and it works, but I wanted to avoid Admin's password prompt... It that possible?? All PC's are running on Windows 7

```
@ECHO OFF

Echo Task Manager

Echo.

runas /user:administrador taskmgr

taskkill /f /FI "memusage gt 400000"

taskkill /IM taskmgr.exe

echo.

Pause
```

Comment: Why doesn't the user have access to Task Manager? are these system services that you're killing? If Task Manager is restricted to administrators, maybe you could also create a group (called Task Managers or something) and give that group specific access to Task Manager - if that's possible in Windows. It might be more beneficial to find a way to do this as a Scheduled Task where the trigger is high memory usage - and then you can just save the admin credentials in the Task (in Windows instead of plain text in a batch file) and have it run with highest elevations.

Comment: The user doesn't have access to Task Manager due to company policies.... There's a main administration that runs all the "service stations".

What happens is that from time to time there's a svchost process that goes crazy and gets all the RAM, and it can be active for a long time and the PC runs very slowly during that time.
By simply killing that process, the PC runs normally again..

Comment: Use `RunAs /savecred`.

Comment: why would the user need to see taskmanager? why not simply kill the tasks with high memory consumption and tell the user through command line what was killed?

Comment: Akina, I tried this, but still asks for password:

runas /savecred /user:COMPUTERNAME\administrador "taskmgr"

Comment: Yes;  There is no other way to a command as another user without either prompting for the password for that user or save the password in the script.

Comment: <q>why would the user need to see taskmanager? why not simply kill the tasks with high memory consumption and tell the user through command line what was killed?</q>

That's a very good question SimonS.... And i suspect that the answer is... Because I'm stupid!... lol

No, I just assumed that since the user doesn't have access to Task Manager, in order to kill a process, I would have to grant him access to Task Manager first....

Comment: I just tried like this and it seems to work just fine! 

@ECHO OFF

Echo Task Manager

Echo.

taskkill /f /FI "memusage gt 400000"

taskkill /IM taskmgr.exe

echo.

Thank You All, specially SimonS for all the tips and suggestions! :)